# getting Moment to work in Clojurescript with cljsjs/moment

Tags: momentjs, clojurescript

In my project.clj I've defined the dependency

```
[cljsjs/moment "2.10.6-0"]
```

and I'm requiring it in my cljs file using

```
(:require [cljsjs.moment :as m])
```

I try and use it like this

```
(m/from-now 3485736776)
```

But it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: cljsjs is not defined`

I also tried

```
(m/fromNow 3485736776)
```

Just in case the function call was wrong, but I get the same error ... any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a explanation in cljsjs's wiki page => [A Quick JavaScript Interoperability Refresher](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Using-Packages#a-quick-javascript-interoperability-refresher)

basically, `require` cljsjs's package without `:as` or `:refer`. and the library--`moment` in your case, available in `js` global namespace. Here is a example from my cljs repl:

```
(require '[cljsjs.moment])
;;=> nil
(js/moment)
;;=> #object[Moment Sat Oct 24 2015 04:29:19 GMT+0700]
(.fromNow (js/moment) 3485736776)
;;=>"a few seconds"
```

Comment: Actually the timestamp needs to be passed into the moment constructor so the answer should be `(.fromNow (js/moment 3485736776))` ... but yes it is used from the `js` global namespace, which was what I'd missed. Strange because I'm using cljsjs/d3 with `:as` and it works great

Answer (score 2):

In `(:require [cljsjs.moment :as m])` remove the `:as m` and that should work. After this the functions in `moment` will appear under `js/`.

See https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Using-Packages for an example using `cljsjs.Showdown`.